# Jquery Mobile Dropdown Formatting Issue

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

Not quite sure why this isn't working. Every time I click the select menu it fills the entire screen. I am trying to get this drop down to perform like a normal drop down box: just show the options with a scroll bar. I guess I'm just going to keep typing because stack overflow is insisting that I add more detail to my post sense it is mostly code. Gotta be honest, I'm pretty pissed off that I even have to be here typing in the first place. It would be GREAT if the DEFAULT SELECT MENU could WORK CORRECTLY.

```
<html>
<head>
<link rel='stylesheet' href='http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0a1/jquery.mobile-1.0a1.min.css' />
<script src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.4.3.min.js'></script>
<script src='http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0a1/jquery.mobile-1.0a1.min.js'></script>
</head>
<body>
<div data-role='page' style='width:300px'>
    <select name='minutesTo' id='minutesTo' data-theme='a' required>
        <option value='00'> 00 </option>
        <option value='01'> 01 </option>
        <option value='02'> 02 </option>
        <option value='03'> 03 </option>
        <option value='04'> 04 </option>                                                                                                                                                                
        <option value='05'> 05 </option>
        <option value='06'> 06 </option>
        <option value='07'> 07 </option>
        <option value='08'> 08 </option>
        <option value='09'> 09 </option>
        <option value='10'> 10 </option>
        <option value='11'> 11 </option>
        <option value='12'> 12 </option>
        <option value='13'> 13 </option>
        <option value='14'> 14 </option>
        <option value='15'> 15 </option>
        <option value='16'> 16 </option>
        <option value='17'> 17 </option>
        <option value='18'> 18 </option>
        <option value='19'> 19 </option>
        <option value='20'> 20 </option>
        <option value='21'> 21 </option>
        <option value='22'> 22 </option>
        <option value='23'> 23 </option>
        <option value='24'> 24 </option>
        <option value='25'> 25 </option>
        <option value='26'> 26 </option>
        <option value='27'> 27 </option>
        <option value='28'> 28 </option>
        <option value='29'> 29 </option>
        <option value='30'> 30 </option>
        <option value='31'> 31 </option>
        <option value='32'> 32 </option>
        <option value='33'> 33 </option>
        <option value='34'> 34 </option>
        <option value='35'> 35 </option>
        <option value='36'> 36 </option>
        <option value='37'> 37 </option>
        <option value='38'> 38 </option>
        <option value='39'> 39 </option>
        <option value='40'> 40 </option>
        <option value='41'> 41 </option>
        <option value='42'> 42 </option>
        <option value='43'> 43 </option>
        <option value='44'> 44 </option>
        <option value='45'> 45 </option>
        <option value='46'> 46 </option>
        <option value='47'> 47 </option>
        <option value='48'> 48 </option>
        <option value='49'> 49 </option>
        <option value='50'> 50 </option>
        <option value='51'> 51 </option>
        <option value='52'> 52 </option>
        <option value='53'> 53 </option>
        <option value='54'> 54 </option>
        <option value='55'> 55 </option>
        <option value='56'> 56 </option>
        <option value='57'> 57 </option>
        <option value='58'> 58 </option>
        <option value='59'> 59 </option>
    </select>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: That didn't work for me. I also tried to use ui-field-contain as its class and that also didn't work.

Comment: I believe that jquery.mobile-1.0a1 means that You are using the jQuery Mobile Alpha 1 version, which was released October 2010... You will have a lot easier if You switch to a newer version, if You can.

Answer (score 0):

You have added width to the the following

```
<div data-role='page' style='width:300px'>// this will give width to only the select element
```

but when u inspect your dropdown, it is created after the your div ends. a seprate div is created for the dropdown, whose width is 100% in absolute position, so for now I feel u should add static width to the dropdown.

https://codepen.io/aayushi_kambariya/pen/vjmJpx

```css
.ui-page {
  width: 300px;
}
```

Comment: This works but also keeps the page at 300px. I only had that because I pulled this segment of code out of my other page. Is there a way to alter the width of that separate div without altering the page width?